# drawing tools on Mapbox

Tags: dictionary, mapbox, polygon, draw

I have added some drawing tools to my Mapbox map using the following code provided on the Mapbox website... https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-draw/

I removed anything to do with the area measurement calculation as I only wanted to be able to draw on the map.

However, the map is set to default draw without having to click the drawing icon. This means when the page opens rather than being able to pan around the map the cursor is a crosshair and begins drawing.

I noted the following section in the script but not sure what to put in place of "draw_polygon" to stop it from being the default.

```
// Set mapbox-gl-draw to draw by default.
// The user does not have to click the polygon control button first.
defaultMode: 'draw_polygon'
});
```

Anyone have any ideas how to stop draw polygon from being the default?

Also any other ideas on other/better drawing tools?

Answer (score 0):

The default mode is `simple_select`, so you can either add this in place of `draw_polygon`, or just remove the `defaultMode` option altogether and it will start in `simple_select` mode.